# AngularJS trigger field validation after form loads

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-validation

I have set of data fields. 
They look like this:

```
// Read-Only
<div class="field-group" ng-if="feature.edit == false">
    <div class="label" ng-class="{'feature-required': field.Validations.Required === true}">{{field.Label}}</div>
    <div class="value">{{field.Value}}</div>
</div>


// Editor
<div class="field-group" ng-show="feature.edit == true">
    <label for="F{{field.FieldID}}">
        <span ng-class="{'feature-required': field.Validations.Required === true, 'feature-notrequired': field.Validations.Required === false}">{{field.Label}}</span>

        <input type="text"
               id="F{{field.FieldID}}"
               name="F{{field.FieldID}}"
               ng-change="onFieldUpdate()"
               ng-model="field.Value"
               jd-field-attributes attr-field="field"
               jd-validate on-error="onFieldError"
               field="field">
    </label>

</div>
```

feature.edit is controlled by button and you can have data read-olny or editable. Each field has some validation, usually, if required it must be different than null. 
I want to trigger that validation after I click edit and input fields show up. 
One way to do it is to loop through all input fields and use jQuery *trigger("change")*. I have to do it with some delay (it takes Angular to populate all fields). 
Is there any way to trigger **ng-change** or run **onFieldUpdate()**, after that input becomes visible?
I have tried **ng-init**, but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using an actual <form> and checking for $pristine, $dirty, etc?

Comment: You can also tie your validation classes logic to include your feature.edit flag. That might be what you're looking for:  (field.Validations.Required === true && feature.edit == true)

Comment: Why don't you use the standard validation directives of angular: required, ng-required, etc.?

Comment: ng-required="feature.edit"

Comment: Couldn't you also use a $watch on your feature.edit and when it becomes true, trigger the onFieldUpdate() function? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: Basically ng-change triggers validation methods that are written in directive (I didn't write them). So whenever user start editing field, onFieldChange fires and if, for example, user clears field that is required, error message shows up. I want that error to show up for invalid fields after they load with some pre-loaded values.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your validation logic to custom validators in the ngModel `$validators` pipeline.  Functions you add to this pipeline will evaluate against the input model value every time it changes and automatically add the associated valid/invalid classes to the input.

Here's an example of how you can add custom validators:

```
app.directive('moreValidation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.first = function(input) {
        return true; // add your custom logic here
      }

      ngModel.$validators.second = function(input) {
        return true;
      }

      ngModel.$validators.third = function(input) {
        return true; 
      }
    }
  };
});

// markup
<input type="text" ng-model="modelObject" more-validation />
```

Here's a small working plnkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mKKuhNqcnGXQ4sMePrym?p=preview